# c# function app: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly ( But I only have one project, no portable)

Tags: c#, function

I am building my first function app.

I use a nuget package which I used a lot before in my xamarin.forms apps. Now, when I init the package I am getting:

This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

But I am using this in my main project. There are no sub projects, no PCL, or anything xamarin related.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

It appear on this line of code:

```
 var config = Kumulos.CurrentConfig.AddKeys(
                        "asd",
                        "123");

                Kumulos.Current.Initialize(config);
            }
```

Whic h is the first time I even reference the nuget package at all...

Comment: You mention that you used the package previously in Xamarin projects, but your current project is not a Xamarin one. Is it a UWP project?

Comment: No, it is a c# function app that is deployed on an azure webservice. before i did use this package inside xamarin.forms, but no I am not

Comment: Kumulos seems specific for Xamarin. Are you sure you can use it in your current project type? For a Xamarin project, the "shared" project does not always contain all code, the "real" code may be in the OS-specific projects (that you apparently don't have)